# MySQL get players rank between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I have a table of players:

```
id  points  last_online
 1     320  2011-07-10
 2    1025  2011-07-05
 3     750  2011-04-25
 4    5000  2011-07-10
 5     525  2011-05-01
```

In order to get a player rank (based on points), I have the following mySQL select:

```
SELECT Player.*,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM players Player_i
      WHERE (Player_i.points, Player_i.id) >= (Player.points, Player.id)
     ) AS rank
FROM players AS Player
WHERE Player.id = 1
```

It works fine. So, the rank for the player ID 1 is 5.

But I want to consider only the players that were online last time in the past 30 days (considering today is 2011-07-10). This way the rank for the player ID 1 would be 3, because the players 3 and 5 were excluded from the rank.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways. First way, edit your query a little:

```
SELECT Player.*,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM players Player_i
      WHERE Player_i.points >= Player.points
      and last_online > subdate(now(), '30 day')
     ) AS rank
FROM players AS Player
WHERE Player.id = 1
and last_online > subdate(now(), '30 day'); -- EDITED to add this line
```

Second way, and the *better* way, is to use a variable (way better performance, and simpler SQL):

```
set @rank := 0;
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1
FROM Player
WHERE last_online > subdate(now(), 30 'day')
ORDER BY points desc;
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect, as it will still show all players--it will just omit the rank (or report 0) for those who have not been online recently.

Comment: You are correct - we have the other half of each other's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE last_online > NOW() - '30 days'` to your query:

```
SELECT Player.*,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM players Player_i
    WHERE (Player_i.points, Player_i.id) >= (Player.points, Player.id)
        AND Player.last_online >= SUBDATE(NOW(), '30 day')
    ) AS rank
FROM players AS Player
WHERE Player.id = 1
    AND Player.last_online >= SUBDATE(NOW(), '30 day');
```

Comment: I don't think so... how does your SQL filter people who haven't logged for a while?

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't understand your question. The last line of the WHERE clause does that...

Comment: but you have to also filter the subselect don't you?

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't believe, so, because the subselect uses **Player.id** in the WHERE clause, so it already only considers values returned in the outter select.

Comment: Actually, as I consider the query, I believe it willy only _return_ players who have been online in the last 30 days, but it will rank them among all players.  So yeah, the sub-select needs to be filtered as well--unless this is the behavior the OP wants :)

Comment: but it will count other players' that haven't been on line recently when counting the rank, but it should *not* count them - see question and see my answer for the condition in the inner select for what I mean

Comment: For some reason, this always return zero rows. Although it is very similar to Bohemian's answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe my date math syntax isn't quite right... It's apparent that @Bohemian uses MySQL a lot more than I do. :) I switched away from MySQL after version 3.23.

Comment: The syntax `now() - '30 days'` won't work: `select now() - '30 days'; --> 20110710223876`. You should use `subdate` or `adddate` which return proper dates. +1 for tenacity and the assist

Comment: Thanks, updated. I should probably delete my answer now that it's practically identical (and less complete) than yours. But I suppose I'll leave it just for historical reasons.